# Execute Dialog Validation on Activation (AEM 5.6.1)

Tags: aem

AEM/CQ5 (5.6.1) appears to have a deficiency in how content validation works in the out-of-the-box product.

Though component dialogs have a mechanism for validation, the validators only get executed when the dialog is open.  The problem is that a component can be added to a page, and without opening the component's dialog, the page can be activated with the unconfigured component.  Even worse, it's possible to activate a page without completing mandatory configuration in its page properties dialog.

I have previously dealt with the latter by creating a replication preprocessor (com.day.cq.replication.Preprocessor) which validated the expected page properties.  This is suboptimal, since it has its own validation logic, which may diverge from the dialog validators.  It also does nothing to validate components on the page.

Is there any way to leverage the validation rules in component dialogs for validating content prior to activation?  If not, do you have any other suggestions for improving pre-activation content (page and component properties) validation?

Answer (score 0):

One option can be to define a flag in component dialog which you can use to show visible notification text to configure the component and update it once it is configured.

It actually is more of a knowledge problem than a product issue.

Aem can be configured for non-technical authors who can add/modify content on author instance and then can submit it for Review via workflow.
The reviewer can then verify and replicate content if found to be fine.

Comment: Thank you.  To confirm, you are suggesting that each component dialog has a hidden `isComplete` field with a default value of `true`, so that once a component dialog has been opened, the property will be set to `true` if and only if the dialog is saved (passes validation)?  The preprocessor would then recurse through the descendants to ensure that every component has the `isComplete` property, cancelling the activation if any components are missing the property?

Comment: I disagree with your point about this being a knowledge issue.  While it is possible to use a Review Before Activation workflow, that's not the only way to use the system.  If the intent were to force all AEM content through a review step, then the workflow should be an on-by-default step necessary for activation.  It also requires a human to manually validate the content, rather than leveraging the validation rules already implemented on the dialogs.  Manual reviews are fine for verifying copy  (text) and layout, but are likely to miss details such as a mandatory `alt` property on an image.